# FEM: periodic solution of 2D Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, periodic-function, fluid-dynamics

Let’s consider a horizontal channel with a round obstacle in the middle.

```
rules = {length -> 2, hight -> 1/2};
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}], 
    Disk[{1, 1/4}, 1/15]] /. rules;
region = RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The flow occurs under the action of horizontal force from initial state at rest. Side boundaries are open on which the periodical condition is specified.

```
op = {
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] + (1 - Exp[-t]), 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y],
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};
bcsp = {
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], 
     x == 0 && 0 < y < hight, TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], 
     x == 0 && 0 < y < hight, TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]],
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
     0 < x < length], 
    DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., 
     x == length && y == hight]} /. rules;
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel1, yVel1, pressure1} = 
    NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcsp, ic}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 5}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}, 
           "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime]
```

Flow is not appeared. It stays trivial.

```
StreamDensityPlot[
 Evaluate[{xVel1[5, x, y], yVel1[5, x, y]}], {x, 
   y} ∈ Ω, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Top], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The problem is that the pressure doen't know that side walls are open. Is it possible to overcome it?

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[pressure1[5, x, y]], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Top], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Is it possible to overcome it and obtain something like that?
[image]

Let me explain why answer below by Alex Trounev does not completely satisfy.
This preriodic solution (velocity and pressure fields) can be appeared in an infinite periodic array of same obstacles. Let's take 5 for example

```
rules = {length -> 2.5, hight -> 1/2};
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}], 
    RegionUnion[Table[Disk[{n 1/2 - 1/4, 1/4}, 1/15], {n, 5}]]] /. 
   rules;
region = RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Let's solve the problem with periodic-like boundary conditions as suggested by Alex Trounev

```
op = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    10^-2 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - (1 - Exp[-t]),
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    10^-2 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};
bcsp = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < hight,
      TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < hight, 
     TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]], 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
     0 < x < length], DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., True]} /. 
   rules;
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel1, yVel1, pressure1} = 
     NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcsp, ic}, {u, v, 
       p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 10}, 
      Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
          "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
            "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}, 
            "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];],
   currentTime];
```

We obtain almost steady velocity and pressure fields
[image][image]

As you can see that periodic pressure appers at the middle (y-profiles are the same) and not at the side walls.

```
Plot[{pressure1[5, 1, y], pressure1[5, 1.5, y], pressure1[5, 0, y], 
  pressure1[5, 2.5, y]}, {y, 0, 1/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, {Red, Dashed, Thick}, {Blue, Dashed, Thick}, 
   Green}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x=1", "x=1.5", "x=0", "x=2.5"}]
```

[image]

Note true periodic pressure depends on y. So `DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., True]` is partial solution because of periodicity is slightly broken near side walls. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In this problem there is no symmetry between left and right side. Why you try to get periodic solution?

Comment: This problem is superposition of symmetry and antisymmetry. In fact it doesn't matter. The obstacle can be moved in center of symmetry.

Comment: You are wrong, just have a look on your picture "something like that". There is no symmetry at all. See also my solution on https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064

Comment: I've updated my post in order the geometry will be symmetric. But it does not help.

Comment: Geometry can by symmetrical, but flow not follows to geometry only. In this case we have trail after body, and there is no symmetrical trail before body.

Comment: When you say the side boundaries are open are you saying that you are trying to model the flow in an infinite periodic array of circular cylinders? Also, are you trying to have a moving cylinder or are you pushing flow past the cylinder?

Comment: @Hugh, 1) yes, I look for the flow in an infinite planar channel with periodic array of circular cylinders. 2) volume force pushes flow past the cylinder. Non-slip condidtion at top and bottom.

Comment: @AlexTrounev how does it explain the problem with pressure?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I look for periodic flow _u(x)=u(x+2)_, periodic pressure _p(x)=p(x+2)_. I don't prescribe the symmetry.

Comment: @RodionStepanov As I explained it in your previous post, there is a trivial solution $p=xt, u=0,v=0} . So, FEM gets this solution first.

Comment: @AlexTrounev there is solution for with periodic velocity field so there is periodic pressure. I have such solution for problem above which obtained with finite difference code.

Comment: @RodionStepanov You did not tell us about problem solved with FDM. Is it non stationary problem?

Comment: @Hugh, I've updated my post to clarify your question.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I look for a steady solution as result of convergence of time dependent problem.  But nonstationary flow can be periodic too.

Comment: @RodionStepanov Now you explained your problem very well, and there is a periodic solution with zero pressure drop. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is periodic solution with zero pressure drop:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
rules = {length -> 2, hight -> 1/2}; reg1 = Disk[{1, 1/4}, 1/15];
reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}], reg1] /. 
   rules;
region = RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01]

mesh["Wireframe"]

op = {\[Rho]*D[u[t, x, y], t] + 
     Inactive[Div][-\[Mu] Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + \[Rho]*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     D[p[t, x, y], x] - (1 - Exp[-t]), \[Rho]*D[v[t, x, y], t] + 
     Inactive[Div][-\[Mu] Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + \[Rho]*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], y], 
    D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y]} /. {\[Mu] -> 10^-3, \[Rho] ->
      1}; 

tInit = 0; {L, H} = {2, .5};
ic = {u[tInit, x, y] == 0, v[tInit, x, y] == 0, p[tInit, x, y] == 0};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    0 < x < L], DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., True]};
bcsp = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < H, 
    TranslationTransform[{L, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == 0 && 0 < y < H, 
    TranslationTransform[{L, 0}]]};
Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]]
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, bcsp, ic}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, tInit, 1}, 
    Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)];]
```

Visualisation

```
Show[{ContourPlot[xVel[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Bottom], AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    Contours -> 20, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400], 
  StreamPlot[
   Evaluate[{xVel[1, x, y], yVel[1, x, y]}], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   StreamStyle -> LightGray, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}]
ContourPlot[pressure[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> 20,
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Bottom], 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107450/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-trounev-fem-periodic-solution-of-2d-navier-stokes).

Comment: This solution sutisfies u(x=0,y)=u(x=L,y) ,v(x=0,y)=v(x=L,y), p(x=0,y)=p(x=L,y) which is not suffient to be periodic.
If function is periodic f(x)=f(x+L) then f'(x)=f'(x+L). So equality of partial derivatives normal to the side boundaries is very much in demand.