# Invalid PeriodicBoundaryCondition for Navier Stokes problem using NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, fluid-dynamics

**Background**: I'm looking to have a 2D re-entrant channel of a geophysical flow that is forced by a wind stress at the surface ("taux"; below) and experiences planetary rotation ("cor"; below). I'm using linear, 2D Navier Stokes with bottom stress (basically Stommel 1948; [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpwGE.png)) and whilst I've got the closed box working (not shown; [2]), I'm having difficulty with having a re-entrant boundary condition.

**Problem**. Running the below code I get a few errors, but the one that concerns me is regarding the PeriodicBoundaryCondition, i.e., when I call NDSolveValue I get:
`DynamicNDSolveValue::fembpf: The boundary condition PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[0,y]==v[1,y]] is not valid.` And again the same error for BC1.

Here is the code, the errors arise after the 'NDSolveValue' line:

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],CellContext->Notebook]
Ω=Region[Rectangle[{0,0},{1,1}]];
BC0=PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[0,y]==u[1,y]];
 BC1=PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[0,y]==v[1,y]];
 BC3 = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0},  y==0];
BC4 = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0},  y==1];
 bcs = {BC0,BC1,BC3,BC4};
 cor[y_]:=-Sin[((y *Pi/180)*90)+Pi/2]
 taux[y_]:=-Cos[(Pi/180*y)*270]
(*x-momentum
y-momentum
incompressible*)

navierstokes = {Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y] - cor[y]*v[x, y] - taux[y] + r*u[x, y], 
    Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y] + cor[y]*u[x, y] + r*v[x, y], Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + 
     Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]}; 

 op = navierstokes /. { r -> 5} ;
 {uVel, vVel,pressure} =   NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v,p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω,Method -> {"FiniteElement",      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1},"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00025}}];
 picture=StreamPlot[{uVel[x,y],vVel[x,y]},{x,y}∈Ω,Sequence[PlotRange->All,StreamScale->{Medium,n,Automatic},Frame->None,Axes->None,AspectRatio->Automatic,PlotLegends->Automatic]];
Show[picture,Graphics[RegionBoundary[Ω]],ImageSize->Medium]
```

I suspect this problem is trivially solved but as I'm very new to Mathematica, I couldn't quite find an example that fixes this problem. Thus, please explain the syntax if you're able to point me in the right direction. Any general tips for fixing FEM issues much appreciated (I've read a lot of SO posts!)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpwGE.png) Stommel, H. (1948). The westward intensification of wind-driven ocean currents. Transactions, American Geophysical Union, 29(2), 202. https://doi.org/10.1029/TR029i002p00202

[2] the closed box version just swaps `BC0` and `BC1` with
`DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0]` and `DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 1]`, respectively.

---

**Update**
Following @AlexTrounev excellent feedback, I learnt the syntax that works for the numerical approach to my problem.

```mathematica
coff=0;
ruu=5;
\[CapitalOmega] = Region[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]];
  bcs = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x,y],x==0,Function[x,x+{1,0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x,y],x==0,Function[x,x+{1,0}]],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[x,y],x==0,Function[x,x+{1,0}]],
 DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0,  y==1&&0<x<1],
 DirichletCondition[ v[x, y] == 0, y==0&&0<x<1]};
  cor[y_] = -Sin[((y *Pi/180)*70) + Pi/2];
  taux[y_] = -Cos[(Pi/180*y)*270] + coff;
  navierstokes = {(p^(1,0))[x, y] - cor[y]*v[x, y] - taux[y] + ruu*u[x, y],
       (p^(0,1))[x, y] + cor[y]*u[x, y] + ruu*v[x, y],
       (u^(1,0))[x, y] + (v^(0,1))[x, y]};
  {uVe, vVe, pressure} =    NDSolveValue[{navierstokes == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement",      
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00025}}];
  puv = StreamPlot[{uVe[x, y], 
     vVe[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
    Sequence[PlotRange -> All, StreamScale -> {Medium, n, Automatic}, 
     Frame -> None, Axes -> None, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]], PlotLabel -> "UV", 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, None}}]
```

[image: Picture of the u and v velocities]

Comment: Is `p` also periodic?

Comment: Yes. Although, I haven't been setting a pressure boundary condition as I'm only interested in gradients of pressure. Is that a problem here? (I think I got unexpected solutions in the non-reentrant case when setting a `p` boundary condition.)

Comment: Update: this feels [relevant](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220631/fem-periodic-solution-of-2d-navier-stokes-equations?rq=1) not sure how to apply it here though.

Comment: Have you any picture related to this flow?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I just uploaded one above. Thanks for the extremely helpful feedback! I did try your exciting algebraic strategy but couldn't find a way to enforce no normal flow (bc1/bc2) on the northern and southern boundaries to get a solution more like pictured above. Very interested to hear if I missed something. I'm having similar issues extending the problem to 3d in a cube [link](https://livenorthumbriaac-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/christopher_bull_northumbria_ac_uk/Ecw8hrZ4ijRJpV5NtZvd1LYBgQ_Tu_uv7rjDtuGBNFUPWA?e=e4Rw8L).

Comment: Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added the wrong code last time, see new update above. I still need to play with your update (although I note you didn't use BC3?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several scenario to solve this problem. First, we solve

```
navierstokes={Derivative[1,0][p][x,y]-cor[y]*v[x,y]-taux[y]+r*u[x,y],Derivative[0,1][p][x,y]+cor[y]*u[x,y]+r*v[x,y],Derivative[1,0][u][x,y]+Derivative[0,1][v][x,y]};
sol0=Solve[Drop[navierstokes,-1]=={0,0},{u[x,y],v[x,y]}]
(*Out[]= {{u[x,y]->-((-r taux[y]+cor[y] (p^(0,1))[x,y]+r (p^(1,0))[x,y])/(r^2+cor[y]^2)),v[x,y]->-((cor[y] taux[y]+r (p^(0,1))[x,y]-cor[y] (p^(1,0))[x,y])/(r^2+cor[y]^2))}}*)
```

Second, we use last equation to derive elliptic PDE for pressure as follows

```
cor[y_] := -Sin[((y*Pi/180)*90) + Pi/2];
taux[y_] := -Cos[(Pi/180*y)*270];
 eqn=navierstokes[[3]]/.{(v^(0,1))[x,y]->D[v[x,y]/.sol0[[1]],y], (u^(1,0))[x,y]->D[u[x,y]/.sol0[[1]],x]}//Simplify
(*Out[]= -(1/(2 (1+2 r^2+Cos[\[Pi] y])^2))(-5 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] y]-4 \[Pi] r^2 Sin[\[Pi] y]-4 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] y]-8 \[Pi] r^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] y]-\[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] y]+4 \[Pi] r Sin[\[Pi] y] (p^(0,1))[x,y]+4 r (1+2 r^2+Cos[\[Pi] y]) (p^(0,2))[x,y]+\[Pi] Sin[(\[Pi] y)/2] (p^(1,0))[x,y]-4 \[Pi] r^2 Sin[(\[Pi] y)/2] (p^(1,0))[x,y]+\[Pi] Sin[(3 \[Pi] y)/2] (p^(1,0))[x,y]+4 r (p^(2,0))[x,y]+8 r^3 (p^(2,0))[x,y]+4 r Cos[\[Pi] y] (p^(2,0))[x,y])*)
```

Third, we derive boundary conditions

```
bc1=v[x,y]/.sol0[[1]]/.y->0
(*Out[]= -((1+r (p^(0,1))[x,0]+(p^(1,0))[x,0])/(1+r^2))*)
bc2=v[x,y]/.sol0[[1]]/.y->1
(*Out[]= -((p^(0,1))[x,1]/r)*)
bc3=u[x,y]/.sol0[[1]]/.y->0
(*Out[]= -((r-(p^(0,1))[x,0]+r (p^(1,0))[x,0])/(1+r^2))*)
bc4=u[x,y]/.sol0[[1]]/.y->1
(*Out[]= -((p^(1,0))[x,1]/r)*)
```

Since we have one second order PDE with periodic boundary condition on `x`, we need to take 2 boundary conditions from `bc1,bc2,bc3,bc4` only. Also we can try to combine all of them. Note, that in a case of `bc1, bc3` we have

```
sol1=Solve[{bc1==0,bc3==0},{(p^(1,0))[x,0], (p^(0,1))[x,0]}]
(*Out[11]= {{(p^(1,0))[x,0]->-1,(p^(0,1))[x,0]->0}}*)
```

Effectively we can combine it as

```
DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == -x, y == 0 && 0 < x < 1]
```

And `bc2, bc4` we can combine as

```
DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == (1 - y)^2, y == 1 && 0 < x < 1]
```

Since function `x` is not periodic, we test last combination

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{eqn == 0 /. r -> 5, 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[x, y], x == 0, 
    Function[x, x + {1, 0}]], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, y == 1 && 0 < x < 1]}, p, 
  Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]]]
```

This solution looks as follows

```
frame = Show[
  DensityPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Norm[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}] /. sol0[[1]] /. sol2[[1]] /. r -> 5], 
   Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 100], 
  StreamPlot[
   Evaluate[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}] /. sol0[[1]] /. sol2[[1]] /. r -> 5, 
   Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]], 
   StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> LightGray, 
   StreamPoints -> 20]]; Show[
 MapAt[Translate[#, {1, 0}] &, frame, 1], frame, 
 MapAt[Translate[#, {-1, 0}] &, frame, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second method is follows. We add artificial viscosity of about 10^-3, then we have

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005]

\[CapitalOmega] = Region[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]];
BC2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == 0, 
   Function[x, x + {1, 0}]];
BC1 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 0, 
   Function[x, x + {1, 0}]];
BC4 = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, (y == 0) && 
   0 < x < 1]; BC3 = 
 PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[x, y], x == 0, 
  Function[x, x + {1, 0}]]; BC5 = 
 DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, (y == 1) && 0 < x < 1];
bcs = {BC2, BC1, BC4, BC5};
cor[y_] := -Sin[((y*Pi/180)*90) + Pi/2]
taux[y_] := -Cos[(Pi/180*y)*270]
(*x-momentum y-momentum incompressible*)

navierstokes = {Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y] - cor[y]*v[x, y] - taux[y] +
     r*u[x, y] - 1/Re0 Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y] + cor[y]*u[x, y] + r*v[x, y] - 
    1/Re0 Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] - 
    1/Re0 Laplacian[p[x, y], {x, y}]};

op = navierstokes /. {r -> 5, Re0 -> 10^3};
{uVel, vVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, p}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];
```

Visualization

```
picture = 
 StreamDensityPlot[{uVel[x, y], 
   vVel[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> LightGray, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


Show[MapAt[Translate[#, {1, 0}] &, picture[[1]], 1], picture[[1]], 
 MapAt[Translate[#, {-1, 0}] &, picture[[1]], 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev. We get the same (see my update) answer now, if I set your bcs to  `{PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], x == 0, 
   Function[x, x + {1, 0}]], 
  PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == 0, Function[x, x + {1, 0}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[p[x, y], x == 0, 
   Function[x, x + {1, 0}]], 
  DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, (y == 0) && 0 < x < 1], 
  DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, (y == 1) && 0 < x < 1]}`. Nice to see how the artificial viscosity is done too (note the typo).