# FEM 2D mesh with inclusion

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I want to create a FEM mesh with an inclusion, but I want to define the coordinates of the edge nodes manually, since I need the nodes for a problem that requires periodic boundary conditions.

[image]

The definition of the geometry is not the problem, but I do not know how to incorporate the coordinated of the edge nodes into the mesh.

Is there a possibility to do it with mathematica?

Thanks in advances.

Max

Comment: Are you trying to find the coordinates of the boundary mesh elements added between the coordinates you specify with the geometry?

Comment: I want to define the nodes on each side of the mesh so that they have on the opposite side a counterpart. Let's say an arbitrary node on the edge has the coordinates (0.0,4.5) then the corresponding node on the opposite edge side should have the coordinates (10.0,4.5), assuming a quadratic mesh geometry with dimensions lets say lx=10 and ly=10.

Comment: Unlike other FEM codes, Mathematica does not require a one-to-one nodal correspondence for the `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like all you want is to control the positions of the nodes at the boundary.

```
<<NDSolve`FEM`
lpts = Cases[
  Table[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
  {a_, b_}/;Abs[a] == 10 || Abs[b] == 10,
  2
];
hexpts = CirclePoints[4, 6];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> Join[lpts, hexpts],
  "BoundaryElements" -> {
    LineElement[Partition[Last@FindShortestTour[lpts], 2, 1, {1, 1}]],
    LineElement[Partition[Range[6], 2, 1, {1, 1}] + Length[lpts]]
  },
  "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0}}
];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
Show[
  mesh["Wireframe"],
  Graphics[{
    Red,
    Point@lpts
  }]
]
```

[image: Mesh with specified edge nodes.]

I'm importing the `FEM` tools from `NDSolve` as I find they allow more control over mesh creation. I'm generating a matrix of regularly spaced points and then using `Cases` to select only the boundary points and saving them as `lpts`. These will be unordered for now. Then I generate the points necessary for the hexagon as `hexpts`.

`ToBoundaryMesh` wants a list of all the coordinates under the `"Coordinates"` argument, so I join `lpts` and `hexpts`. Then I add some `"BoundaryElements"`. The first `LineElement` is the square outer edge. I'm using `FindShortestTour` to find the ordering that gives me a square and then partitioning this ordering to give me a list of consecutive point numbers like `{{1, 2}, {2, 3},...,{n - 1, n}, {n, 1}}`. This part wants just the position in the `"Coordinates"` list and not the actual coordinates themselves. Then I do the same thing for the hexagonal points which will be at the very end of the list, so I add the length of `lpts` to all of those positions. The last step of creating the boundary mesh is to specify that the hexagon at the centre should be a hole.

I generate a full mesh from this boundary mesh. You should be able to pass this mesh directly to `NDSolve` as you might any other type of mesh. Finally, I'm displaying the mesh along with the `lpts` I generated originally to make sure they match the edge nodes. You should be able to customize the `lpts` to be whatever you like. I tried generating a few different `lpts` and they always seemed to match the nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats basically what I wanted. But there is one more thing... a refinement is is quite easy to incorporate via `increment=0.1; lpts = Cases[
  Table[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10,increment}, {y, -10, 10, increment}], 
  {a_, b_}/;Abs[a] == 10 || Abs[b] == 10,
  2
];` But a coarsening does not really work out, let's say by `increment =2`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Max It's being limited by the default value of `MaxCellMeasure`. Try changing it to something larger like `mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 2]` or higher and it should work, though there does seem to be an upper limit. If `increment` is higher than 5, I can't seem to get the mesh to only use those nodes. This is probably due to the hexagon in the centre limiting the maximum cell size.

Answer (score 6):

*Mathematica* does not require a one-to-one nodal correspondence for the [`PeriodicBoundaryCondition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html) to work.  However, care must be taken to ensure that `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` does not share nodes with a [`DirichletCondition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html).

Here is an example adapted for an inclusion taken from the documentation for `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`.  Please note that there can be artefacts introduced due to implied NeumannConditions on the "source" boundary as discussed in this [MSE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204546/understanding-periodicboundaryconditions).  That is why I applied forward and reverse PBC's.  It seemed to work.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{length, height, xc, yc, r} = {1, 2, 0, 0, 1/8};
{sx, sy, fx, fy} = {-length/2, -height/2, length/2, height/2};
disk = Region@Disk[{xc, yc}, r];
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{sx, sy}, {fx, fy}], disk];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0005, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5];
pde = ((Inactive[
       Div][(-{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}]) - If[1/4 fx <= x <= 3/4 fx && sy/4 <= y <= fy/4, 1., 
     0.] == 0)
Subscript[Γ, D] = 
  DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y] == 0, (y <= sy || y >= fy) && sx < x <= fx];
pbcf = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == sx && sy <= y <= fy, 
   TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]];
pbcr = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == fx && sy <= y <= fy, 
   TranslationTransform[{-length, 0}]];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{pde, pbcf, pbcr, Subscript[Γ, D]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
cp = ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Show[MapAt[Translate[#, {length, 0}] &, cp, 1], cp, 
 MapAt[Translate[#, {-length, 0}] &, cp, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Results]

For completeness, I show the artefact with specifying only one PBC resulting in a no flux condition on the source wall.

```
pbc = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == sx && sy <= y <= fy, 
   TranslationTransform[{length, 0}]];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{pde, pbc, Subscript[Γ, D]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
cp = ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Show[MapAt[Translate[#, {length, 0}] &, cp, 1], cp, 
 MapAt[Translate[#, {-length, 0}] &, cp, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Artefact]