# NDSolve for Laplace equation on disk is not working

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I want to solve the laplace equation on the disk using NDSolve.
Particularly I want to solve the problem $$\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial r^2 } +r^{-1}\frac{\partial u }{\partial r }+r^{-2}\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial \theta^2 }=0$$ with $$u(a,\theta )=f(\theta )$$ and $0<\theta <2 \pi $.

Also set $a=3$ and $f(\theta )=\begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi \\ \sin^2 \theta & \pi < \theta < 2 \pi \end{cases}$.

So my attemped code is

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3;
f[theta_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= theta <= π}, {(Sin[theta])^2, π < theta < 2*π}}]

PDE = (D[u[r, theta], {r, 2}]) + r^-1*(D[u[r, theta], {r, 1}]) + 
    r^-2*(D[u[r, theta], {theta, 2}]) == 0;

BC = u[r, theta /. theta -> 0] == u[r, theta /. theta -> 2*π]

IC = u[r /. r -> a, theta] == f[theta];

sol = NDSolve[{PDE, BC, IC }, u, {r, theta} ∈ Disk[]];

Plot3D[u[r, theta], {r, 0, a}, {theta, 0, 2*π}]
```

However the code is not working, I can't figure out why.
Can you explain my mistake?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0, DirichletCondition[u[r, θ] == Piecewise[{{1, 0 < θ <= π}, {Sin[θ]^2, π < θ <= 2 π}}], r == 3 && 0 < θ < 2 π], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, θ], θ == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, 2 π}]]}, u, {r, 0, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}}]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

3 issues here.

1. You've mixed up polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates. Since the equation is defined in polar coordinates, the shape of domain of definition is no longer a `Disk` but a rectangle. (Even if it's a disk, it should be `Disk[{0, 0}, a]` rather than `Disk[]`. )
2. `Plot3D[u[r, theta], …]` is obviously wrong, you should call the `sol` with `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), or use `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve`.
3. There's an issue related to periodic b.c. of `FiniteElement` method, which is discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871). To obtain the desired solution, we need to set 2 `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`s and a ghost layer.

The following is the fixed code:

```
fem[measure_: Automatic] := {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure};

a = 3; eps = 10^-5;
f[theta_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= theta <= π}}, (Sin[theta])^2]

PDE = (D[u[r, theta], {r, 2}]) + r^-1*(D[u[r, theta], {r, 1}]) + 
    r^-2*(D[u[r, theta], {theta, 2}]) == 0;

BC = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, theta], theta == -Pi && r < a, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 π}]],
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, theta], theta == Pi + eps && r < a, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -2 π}]]};

IC = u[a, theta] == f[theta];

sol = NDSolve[{PDE, BC, IC}, u, {r, 0, a}, {theta, -Pi, π + eps}, 
   Method -> fem[10^-3/2]];

RevolutionPlot3D[u[r, th] /. sol // Evaluate, {r, 0, a}, {th, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But since setting `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` is so troublesome, why not staying in Cartesian coordinates?:

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == f[ArcTan[x, y]], True]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, a], Method -> fem[10^-3/2]]

With[{ϵ = 10^-6}, 
 Manipulate[Plot[{u[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]] /. sol[[1]], sol2[x, y]} // 
    Evaluate, {x, -Sqrt[a^2 - y^2], Sqrt[a^2 - y^2]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {y, -a + ϵ, a - ϵ}]]
```

[image]

### Remark

1. I haven't set `"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement"` instead of the ghost layer, because this trick isn't working well in this case. This might be related to the removable singularity at $r=0$.
2. I've moved the domain of $\theta$ from $[0,2\pi]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ to make it consistent with range of [2-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).
3. If you check the last animation carefully, you'll find small but obvious discrepancy between the 2 solutions. Further comparing them with the analytic solution (you can find it in [Nasser's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269077/1871)), you'll see the solution in Cartesian coordinates is more accurate. Setting a even smaller option value for `MaxCellMeasure` in polar coordinates does help, but the convergence speed is not great. OK, now we have another reason for staying in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't realized `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[]` has its own set of problems. But it's sooo tempting to do things in polar coordinates (your good point about solving in the Cartesian form aside)!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem was with the periodic BC and JM's above showed how to handle this periodic BC.

This below shows that `DSolve` can also solve this analytically and compares the output from the numerical solution by JM and the analytical solution.

note: used $-\pi\dots\pi$ and not $0\dots 2\pi$. Also note the periodic boundary conditions syntax for the analytical solution.  This now gives same result as the numerical solution.

### Analytical solution

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3;
f[r_, θ_] :=  Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= θ <= π}, {Sin[θ]^2, -π < θ < 0}}]

BC1 = u[a, θ] == f[a, θ]
BC2 = {u[r, -Pi]==u[r, Pi], (D[u[r, θ], θ]/. θ -> -Pi)==(D[u[r, θ], θ] /. θ -> Pi)};

sol = DSolveValue[{PDE, BC1, BC2}, u, {r, θ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], sol[r, θ]}, 
     {θ, -π, π}, {r, 0, a}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Numerical solution

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3;
PDE = Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
f[r_, θ_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= θ <= π}, {Sin[θ]^2, -π < θ < 0}}]
BC1 = DirichletCondition[u[r, θ] == f[r, θ], r == a && 0 < θ < 2 π];
BC2 = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, θ], θ == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, 2 π}]];
solN = NDSolveValue[{PDE, BC1, BC2}, u, {r, 0, a}, {θ, 0, 2 π}];
ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], solN[r, θ]}, 
      {θ, 0, 2 π}, {r, 0, a}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This isn't the end. In numeric solution you need to set 2 periodic b.c. as discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871), otherwise the result is undesired. (Just compare the numeric solution with the analytic one.)

Comment: @xzczd  Feel free to edit or make new answer for the corrected numerical solution Part. As I said in my answer, for the numerical part I just used the solution given by comment above. I am not as familiar with periodic condition setting for NDSolve as with DSolve.

Comment: OK. I posted an answer.

Comment: It is interesting that Poisson formula `1/2/Pi*Integrate[(9 - r^2)*
   Piecewise[{{1, t >= 0 && t <= Pi}, {Sin[t]^2, 
       t > Pi && t < 2*Pi}}]/(9 - 6*r*Cos[t - \[Theta]] + r^2), {t, 0,
    2*Pi}, Assumptions -> 
   r >= 0 && r <= 3 && \[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] < 2*Pi]` produces a different symbolic solution  (too long to be presented here).