# Solving PDE with Dirichlet, Neumann and Boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the following PDE:
$$
u_{xx} + u_{yy}
=
\begin{cases}
- \cos(x) \quad -\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi/2, \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The domain is $\Omega = [-\pi,\pi] \times [0,2]$. The boundary conditions are periodic at $x = \pm \pi$ - $u(-\pi,y) = u(\pi,y)$ - and $u(x,0) = 0$ (Dirchlet) and $u_y(x,2) = 0$ (Neumann).

I am able to solve the PDE if I choose all of conditions to be Dirichlet. I cannot, however, solve the PDE in the case where I have a combination of Neumann, Dirichlet, Periodic boundary conditions. I have no idea how to implement the Neumann boundary condition appropriately. Also my implementation of periodic boundary conditions gives errors.

```
Ω = Rectangle[{-Pi, 0}, {Pi, 2}];

op = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 
   Piecewise[{{-Cos[x], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2}, {0, x < -Pi/2}, {0, 
      x > Pi/2}}, {x, -Pi, Pi}];

Subscript[Γ, 
   D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 2 ]};

mapping = 
  Last[FindGeometricTransform[{{-Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 2}}, {{Pi, 0}, {Pi, 
      2}}]];

Subscript[Γ, P] = 
  PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -Pi, mapping];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D], 
    Subscript[Γ, P]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
  ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic];
```

Answer (score 5):

4 issues here, 2 are simple mistakes, 2 are not.

1. Though it happens not to cause problem in this case, your understanding for syntax of `Piecewise` is wrong, please check its document carefully. The correct one should be `Piecewise[{{-Cos[x], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2}}]`.
2. You've inverted the direction in `FindGeometricTransform`.
3. Currently `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` and `DirichletCondition` cannot overlap even at points, **personally** I think this design is a bit unnecessary and inconvenient.
4. There's an issue related to periodic b.c. of `FiniteElement` method, which is discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871). To obtain the desired solution, we need to set 2 `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`s and a ghost layer.

To sum up:

```
eps = 0.1;
Ω = Rectangle[{-Pi, 0}, {Pi + eps, 2}];
offset = 1.5;
op = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 
   Piecewise[{{-Cos[x], -Pi/2 + offset < x < Pi/2 + offset}}];

Subscript[Γ, D] = 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0];

mapping = Last[FindGeometricTransform[{{Pi, 0}, {Pi, 2}}, {{-Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 2}}]];
mappinginverse = 
  Last[FindGeometricTransform[{{-Pi, 0}, {-Pi, 2}}, {{Pi, 0}, {Pi, 2}}]];
Subscript[Γ, 
   P] = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -Pi && 0 < y < 2, mapping], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == Pi + eps && 0 < y < 2, mappinginverse]};

ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D], 
    Subscript[Γ, P]}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
ufunwrong = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == 0, Subscript[Γ, D], 
    Last@Subscript[Γ, P]}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];

With[{y = 1.5}, 
 Plot[{ufun[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi], y], ufunwrong[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi], y]} // 
   Evaluate, {x, -Pi, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]]
```

[image]

Notice I've set `offset = 1.5` to illustrate the necessity of double periodic b.c., for your original problem, set `offset = 0`.

"Wait, where's the Neumann b.c.?" Your Neumann b.c. corresponds to a zero `NeumannValue`. As mentioned in **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue`:

> ...not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

So you don't need to write code for your Neumann b.c..

Comment: When I run your code, I get the error: `NDSolveValue::femnodpbc: DirichletCondition can not be present on the target boundary of a PeriodicBoundaryConditon.` Seems like the same issue persists.

Comment: @u Which version are you in? Anyway, try the editted code tested in 13.2.1.

Comment: I am running version 12, hmm. Let me see if I can find an update. If not, what seems to be going on? Why do I get the error?

Comment: @user82261 Have you tested the updated code in v12? If it still doesn't work, I'd say it's a bug of earlier version.

Answer (score 3):

**modified**

Thanks to @xzczd for the helpful discussion

Here my simplified version without ghost layer and `mapping`:

The `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`'s have to be defined on both sides `x==-Pi` and `x==Pi`. `y==0` must be excluded, otherwise there is a conflict with `DirichletCondition`.

Using a triangle-mesh `NDSolve` is able to correctly handle the periodic bc's

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{-Pi, 0}, {Pi , 2}];
offset = 1.5;
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x,y }] == -Cos[x] Boole[-Pi/2 + offset < x< Pi/2 + offset];
\[CapitalGamma]D = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0];

\[CapitalGamma]P = {
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y],x ==  \[Pi] && 0 < y <= 2, TranslationTransform[{-2 Pi, 0}]], 
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -\[Pi] && 0 < y <= 2, TranslationTransform[{2 Pi, 0}]]}

ufun = NDSolveValue[{pde, \[CapitalGamma]D, \[CapitalGamma]P},u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
Method -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" ->"TriangleElement",    "MeshOrder" -> 1}}]


Plot3D[ufun[x, y], Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]],AxesLabel -> {x, y, u[x, y]}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}]
```

[image]

The periodic boundary conditions are well fullfilled now

```
Plot [Evaluate[Table[ufun[x, y], {y, Subdivide[0, 2, 10]}]], {x, -Pi,Pi}]
```

[image]

The solution QP asked for follows with `offset==0`

Comment: 1. It should be `-Cos[x]`. 2. One of your `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` is actually ignored, try `pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == -Cos[x] Boole[-Pi/2 + offset < x < Pi/2 + offset];` and then check the derivative as shown my answer. The ghost layer cannot be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer `-Cos[x]`.

Comment: @xzczd In the link "ghost layer" you mentioned there was a hint: "For triangle-mesh epsilon==0 is possible". But here in this problem not?

Comment: That's another way to go, but you need to set `"MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement`. (This isn't the default setting. ) BTW, you forgot to remove the `eps` in your code.

Comment: @xzczd I thought so too, but it doesn't work on v12.2 for this example!

Comment: How do you set it?

Comment: I tried `ufun = NDSolveValue[{pde , \[CapitalGamma]D  , \[CapitalGamma]P }, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", 
      "MeshOrder" -> 1}}`

Comment: .. and got error `NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where x==\[Pi]&&0<y<=2 was True, so PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u,x==\[Pi]&&0<y<=2,TransformationFunction[{{1,0,-2 \[Pi]},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}]] will effectively be ignored.`

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in v13.2.1. Instead of `0 < y <= 2`, using `0 < y < 2` seems to circumvent it, try it out in v12.2 :) .