# Solving Poisson PDE with NDSolve and incomplete BC specifications

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

When solving the following PDE with a missing BC on the fourth edge ($y=1$):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] == (1-y), 
           DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0,(y==0||x==-1||x==1)]}, u, {x,y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1,0},{1,1}]]
```

MMA returns an output. I would have expected an error such as missing BC. It seems that it implicitly considered a Neumann condition $\partial_n u = 0$ on $y=1$:

```
Plot[D[sol[x, y], y] /. y -> 1, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Plus, I get the same output when I specify `NeumannValue`:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] == 1-y + NeumannValue[0, y == 1], 
               DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0,(y==0||x==-1||x==1)]}, u, {x,y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1,0},{1,1}]]
```

Is there a rational behind the apparent autocompletion of missing BCs with 0 Neumann conditions?

Comment: **It seems that it implicitly considered a Neumann condition** Yes. That is correct. When solving using FEM method that is the case. From help **so not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition** this means NDSolve also used FEM to solve your pde (because you used `DirichletCondition` .  see [NeumannValue.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html)

Comment: @Nasser Where is this in the help? On the contrary, the doc for `NDSolve` (v13) states "The differential equations must contain enough initial or boundary conditions to determine the solutions for the yi completely."  *Edit* In the NeumannValue doc, OK, thank you.

Comment: @Nasser It seems FEM is used for some reasons other than `DirichletCondition`: `NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] == (1 - y), u[x, 0] == 0, u[-1, y] == 0, 
  u[1, y] == 0}, u, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` returns the same output. Anyway, you answered my question. I don't know if I should close my question, as it can be found in the doc but not easily.

Comment: It could be that FEM is selected even if you do not use `DirichletCondition`. It depends on the problem. I am not sure how it decides internally. But I think if you use `DirichletCondition` or explicit `Neumann` then it does select FEM in that case since these go with FEM method. You could leave the question open if you want, may be someone will have more official answer and more details. It is up to you.

Comment: If you search "Neumann zero" in this site, you'll find quite a few related posts e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222373/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282379/1871 , but I cannot find a post focusing on this topic at least for now.

Comment: Here are rules by which the FEM is chosen: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#62890509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call 'auto completion' of a Neumann value in the finite element method is in fact a necessity from the derivation of the finite element method. This is explained in the [notes of NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html#975107208). An explanation with more text is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1344839347).

To find out in what cases the FEM is chosen automatically, have a look in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#62890509). I have added a link to this from the NDSolve and the NDSolveValue ref pages under the 'Tech Notes' button.