# PDE Problem: NDsolve give the results inconsistent with the initial state

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

We are solving the non-linear PDE, like this

```
Vtrap[x_, y_] := 1/4  (x^2 + (\[Omega]y/\[Omega]x)^2 y^2);
eqs = {I D[\[Psi]1[t, x, y], 
      t] == (-Laplacian[\[Psi]1[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
      Vtrap[x, y] \[Psi]1[t, x, y] + 
      c0 (Abs[\[Psi]1[t, x, y]]^2) \[Psi]1[t, x, y])};

bc = {\[Psi]1[0, x, y] == 
    initial\[Psi]1[x, y], \[Psi]1[t, -halfLx, y] == \[Psi]1[t, halfLx,
      y], \[Psi]1[t, x, -halfLy] == \[Psi]1[t, x, halfLy]};
```

Where the **parameters and initial state** are given by

```
{\[Omega]x, \[Omega]y, \[Omega]z} = 2 Pi {20, 20, 600};
ah = 1;
x0 = 40 ah;
halfLx = x0;
halfLy = x0;
c0 = 36167.02072294063`;
c2 = -180.72215226953406`;
numDiscrete = 200.;
\[Delta]x = 2 halfLx/(numDiscrete);
\[Delta]y = 2 halfLy/(numDiscrete);
datax = Table[x, {x, -halfLx, halfLx, \[Delta]x}];
datay = Table[y, {y, -halfLy, halfLy, \[Delta]y}];
datapsi0 = ToExpression@Import["datapsi0.csv"];
nx = Length@datapsi0;
ny = Length@First@datapsi0;
data\[Psi]Interpolation = 
  Catenate[
   ParallelTable[{{datax[[ix]], datay[[iy]]}, 
     datapsi0[[ix, iy]] // Chop}, {ix, 1, nx}, {iy, 1, ny}]];
kh = 1.22 1.72;
initial\[Psi]1[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[
  Interpolation[data\[Psi]Interpolation][x, y] (-I Cos[kh x/2]^2)]
```

The imported file `Import["datapsi0.csv"]` can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F_wGPnX_aqz1GGJpDyYZeHx-Q8HDmUv9/view?usp=sharing).

**Solving:**

```
solv = NDSolve[{eqs, bc}, \[Psi]1, {t, 0, .1}, {x, -halfLx, 
   halfLx}, {y, -halfLy, halfLy}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", {"SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}}]
```

The results show

```
{DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[ Abs[\[Psi]1[0, x, y] /. solv[[1]]]], {x, -halfLx, 
   halfLx}, {y, -halfLy, halfLy}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All],
 DensityPlot[{Abs[Evaluate[initial\[Psi]1[x, y]]]}, {x, -halfLx, 
   halfLx}, {y, -halfLy, halfLy}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]

**Problem:**

Obviously, the result given by NDsolve at `t==0`(left) is different from the initial state `initial\[Psi]1[x, y]`(right).

I guess the reason is that the discretized space grid is too coarse, so it ignores the details therein. If the guess is correct, how can we control the size of the grid here? If not, what should we do?

Comment: And notice that for problem defined on regular domain, esp. for those with periodic b.c., it's probably better to use `TensorProductGrid` method rather than `FiniteElement` at least for now, because of the issue discussed here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204546/1871

Comment: If the t=0 start configuration is not periodic in both dimensions, most approximation schemata will ignore the nonperiodic part, because of suppression of the edge and more apparent corner noise generation. If I should code such a problem I would symmetize the start configuration as a first step.  Reminds me of the old problem why not to place your audio boxes in the corner or in a knot of the lowest eigenstates.