NDSolve: Prescribe a linear constraint on a boundary
This is a representative volume element problem on a unit square.
I would like to apply the following linear constraint on a boundary:
$u(x,1)=u(x,0)+0.3$
How can do this? There seems to be no way. What I have so far works, but it is not the problem I want to solve. The line to be modified from periodic BC to the above linear constraint comes directly after the last comment. This is what I have so far:
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Generate regions and mesh *)
inclusions = Region[Disk[{1/2, 1/2}, 1/4]];
matrix = Rectangle[];
RVE = RegionDifference[matrix, inclusions];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RVE]
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
    "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1.5, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.1];
mesh["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Gray], FaceForm[White]}]]

(* Define operator*)
Y[x_, y_] = 10 + 100000 Boole[RegionMember[inclusions, {x, y}]];
nu = 30/100;
op = {Inactive[Div][{{0, -((nu*Y[x, y])/(1 - nu^2))}, 
                     {-((1 - nu)* Y[x, y])/(2*(1 - nu^2)), 0}} . 
                     Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
                     Inactive[Div][{{-(Y[x, y]/(1 - nu^2)), 
                     0}, {0, -((1 - nu)*Y[x, y])/(2*(1 - nu^2))}} . 
                     Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}], 
                     Inactive[Div][{{0, -((1 - nu)* Y[x, y])/(2*(1 - nu^2))}, 
                     {-((nu*Y[x, y])/(1 - nu^2)), 0}} . 
                     Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Inactive[
                     Div][{{-((1 - nu)*Y[x, y])/(2*(1 - nu^2)), 
                     0}, {0, -(Y[x, y]/(1 - nu^2))}} . 
                     Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]};

(* Solve and show result *)
{ufun, vfun} = NDSolveValue[
    {op == {0, 0},
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y == 0],
    DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y == 0],
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0}, x == 1 && y == 0],
    DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == 0}, x == 1 && y == 0],
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0.3}, x == 0 && y == 1],
    DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y == 1],
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0.3}, x == 1 && y == 1],
    DirichletCondition[{v[x, y] == 0}, x == 1 && y == 1],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && y == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], 0 < y < 1 && x == 0, TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]],
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[x, y], 0 < y < 1 && x == 0, TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]],
    (* this line needs to be adopted such that u[x,1]==u[x,0]+0.3 *)
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], 0 < x < 1 && y == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]]
    }
 , {u, v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
mesh = ufun["ElementMesh"];
Show[{mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]], 
   NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {ufun, vfun}, 
   "ScalingFactor" -> 1][
   "Wireframe"[
   "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}]



The given constraint isn't enough for determining a solution, you still need to add constraint for derivative in $y$ direction. 2. I think a change of variable will help?


Could you please give a link to the problem you try to reproduce?

@xzczd: It seems that when no Dirichlet BC are explicitly specified, zero Neumann BC are assumed by default. This is what I want. For example, just commenting out all the periodic BC, it works, even when only Dirichlet BC are applied at the corners.

@Alex Trounev: I would like to prescribe an average deformation on a representative volume element while keeping the boundary displacement such that the deformed RVE tesselates. An example implementation is here: https://imechanica.org/files/pbc.pdf. In Abaqus, one can simply define linear constraints between DOF, just like the equation above in my question. I am certain there must be a way to do this in MMA as well.

I think I found how to handle this. The function PeriodicBoundaryCondition[...] allows for "generalized" PBC that allow to specify a linear constraint.

"It seems that when no Dirichlet BC are explicitly specified, zero Neumann BC are assumed by default. " Yes, this is the design. But when only one PeriodicBoundaryCondition is specified in certain direction, zero NeumannValue will still be imposed. This is a serious issue, since PeriodicBoundaryCondition is necessary for your problem, you need to know it, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204546/1871

@xzczd: I was able to enforce one part of the PBC, but ran exactly into the problems that you just mentioned, namely the propagated zero Neumann BC. The issue is that the Neumann constraint is also periodic, i.e. the outflux on one side has to equal the influx on the other side, but the exact value is not prescibed. Not sure how to handle this in MMA.

@xzczd: I did it, but I had to use the hacky "Ghost Layer" approach from the link you provided. Thank you very much.

We may now either delete this question, or I provide the solution I found as an answer, which is basically the ghost layer approach that has been detailed at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204546/1871 applied to my problem. What do you prefer?
